# How can I smooth sharp edges in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, data, smoothing

I have this [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gyomkgedgo8alpd/Ddata.dat?dl=0) and there are some zigzag behaviors around the sharp edges

```
Ddata = Get["C:\\....\\data.dat"];
ListDensityPlot[Ddata, PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}, All}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Gray, Blue}, Rescale[#, {-3, 3}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

I have two questions:

1. as you can see the zigzag is located by the yellow arrows. I tried to smooth that using  `InterpolationOrder -> 5` and `MaxPlotPoints -> 400` but did not work. How can I Smooth that?
2. How can I keep the hexagon shape with the white region When I set  `InterpolationOrder->0`? because this is what I get when doing that

[image]

Comment: What happens if you add **PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"**?

Comment: @Moo, I tried that too, but gives the same output

Comment: Click the link in the question (the word data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your color function combined with `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` seem to be interfering with the built-in interpolation of the `ListDensityPlot[]`.

The solution below uses a built-in color gradient and puts the Z range limits in `PlotRange` and uses `ClippingStyle-> Automatic` to fill in the regions who's values are outside of the Z range.

```
ListDensityPlot[Ddata, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}, {-3, 3}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", "Reverse"}], 
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Here it is with your original colors:

```
ListDensityPlot[Ddata, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}, {-3, 3}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Gray, Blue}, #] &), 
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: that is great. Any idea how to solve the second question, please?

Comment: Interpolation order zero will make the edges jagged again but If that's what you need I can take a look tomorrow.  Maybe some combination of the RegionFunction option and hexRegion = ConvexHullRegion[Ddata] and